# Robot Framework-Test setup Teardown Specific to Test case

Tags: robotframework

We know that robot framework provides us suit setup, teardown and Test Setup, teardown option while we execute out Robot test script. But, I am stuck in a situation where I have few test cases for which the test teardown is different and some other set for with some other set of Tear down. The main constraint is I have to execute all these test cases in the single suite at a stretch to make some dependency test cases to execute.

How to do custom Test Setup/Teardown with respect to different test sets in the same Test suite?

Comment: Have you read the user guide? There is a [whole section](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-setup-and-teardown) on test specific setups and teardowns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @Bryan Oakley, read the manual. In the first section you'll find this sentence which I believe answers your question:

> Individual test cases can also have their own setup or teardown. They
>   are defined with the [Setup] or [Teardown] settings in the test case
>   table and they override possible Test Setup and Test Teardown setting...